# Can't bind to 'suggestions' since it isn't a known property of 'p-autoComplete'

Tags: autocomplete, primeng, angular5

I have installed primeng on angular 5 project.
I am using p-autoComplete component but this error occurs now.
How should I do to fix this error?

This is my source code.

```
<h3 class="first">Basic</h3>
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="country" [suggestions]="filteredCountriesSingle"  (completeMethod)="filterCountrySingle($event)" field="name" [size]="30"
placeholder="Countries" [minLength]="1"></p-autoComplete>
```

Comment: Update the  latest version package of primeng to 5-2-0-rc1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually it's a problem of import. Check your `app.module.ts` file.

It should contain these lines :

```
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {AutoCompleteModule} from 'primeng/autocomplete';
// other imports


@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    AutoCompleteModule,
    // ...
 ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Cant resolve the 'primeng/primeng',the error is as follows,ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'primeng/primeng' in 'E:\OMS-project\Conflux-Angular-Project\src\app'

Comment: It need not be the ap.module.ts , may be whatever your local module.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {AutoCompleteModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
// other imports


@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    AutoCompleteModule,
    // ...
 ],
  exports: [
    AutoCompleteModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```